# Reference on Fixed Point Theory

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, fixed-point-theorems

Could you please recommend me some references for Fixed Point Theory? I am after references containing the main fixed point theorems, their variants, and sufficient (neccessary?) conditions for uniqueness of the fixed points. Mainly I've been looking at Brouwer's and Kakutani's, but any others like Banach's are welcome. I searched here in stack exchange but I don't think I saw much covering these aspects in a comprehensive manner.

Comment: Evans "Partial Differential Equations" contains a whole chapter about employing various fixed points theorem to establish existence result of solutions of various types of nonlinear PDEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Granas-Dugundji's book on fixed point theory is a good starting point for an encyclopedic survey of the classical fixed point theory of continuous mappings including some of the modern extensions as well.

Fixed Point Theory

Authors: Granas, Andrzej, Dugundji, James

ISBN 978-0-387-21593-8

Answer (score 2):

Try these books:

- [Fixed Point Theory and Applications](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511543005) by Agarwal et al.
- [Iterative Approximation of Fixed Points](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-72234-2) by Berinde

Comment: Great recommendations!